# How to remove invalid characters like &nbsp from my CSV within Excel without using any other programming environment

Tags: excel, vba, csv, text

I have a CSV file but I am told it contains invalid characters (&nbsp, etc). How do I clean it up within Excel? This is assuming you do not have any other programming tools, just Excel on a Mac or Windows computer. The purpose is to transform a CSV file so that it is free of these illegal characters.

Comment: One of the methods is to use a macro. The code for this is below in the answer section. More methods are welcome. Please share.

Comment: It would help to add a little more context here.  how are you generating the file and what is it being used for?

Comment: Did you post that question just so you could immediately post your code? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: @teylyn  - thank you, the purpose was to indeed help the community by posting my own method, and hoping that there was a better or shorter macro.

Comment: @TimWilliams, thank you. I am just an end user who is handy with excel. The file was sent to me generated from an unknown system, and needs to be uploaded into another web-based application, and all I kept getting was a message saying "invalid character". So I did some noodling myself and came up with this macro, hoping the community might have a shorter one :)

Comment: @teylyn, actually, there is nothing wrong with posting and answering your own question. See [this blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: @smead That post is 5 years old. Now we have Documentation.

Comment: @teylyn Well, it's still in the [SO help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @Slaks thank you for helping clean up the code!

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a CSV file, there's no reason not to just modify the file in place.  Loading it into Excel is probably a bad idea if you're just going to turn around and use it as input for another process, because you run into issues with localization, automatic conversion of numbers, decimals being converted to scientific notation, etc., etc.

This is much better (and blazingly fast - a 20MB test file took less than a second):

```
Private Sub ScrubCsv(filepath As String)
    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    Dim buffer As String
    With fso.OpenTextFile(filepath)
        buffer = .ReadAll
        .Close
    End With

    With New RegExp
        .Pattern = "[^ -~\n\r]"  'All printable chars, plus CR and LF
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        buffer = .Replace(buffer, vbNullString)
    End With

    With fso.CreateTextFile(filepath)
        .Write buffer
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Note that you need to either add references to the MS Scripting Runtime and MS VBScript Regular Expressions or change to late binding.

Called like this:

```
ScrubCsv "C:\some.csv"
```

Comment: sorry for a noob question: Would you please be kind to share what tools you would need to run your type of code?

Comment: @SuhailHalai - In the VB editor: Tools->References..., then check the boxes for "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and "Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions x.x".

Comment: thank you for the clarification! For reference for others, in Excel for Mac it is within Menu > Tools > Macro > Visual Basic Editor

Answer (score 0):

ONE SOLUTION IS TO USE THIS MACRO (ADJUST THE CELL RANGE TO WHAT YOU NEED):

```
Sub CleanData()
' CleanData Macro
MsgBox "Junk chars will be removed in the specified cells and they will be colored blue.", vbOKCancel
Dim Rng As Range
For Each Rng In ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A1000").Cells 'adjust cell range for use
   Rng.Interior.Color = RGB(200, 200, 255)
   Rng.Replace What:="#NAME?", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
   Rng.Value = AlphaNumericOnly(Rng.Value)
Next
MsgBox "Junk Chars were removed successfully and cells have been colored blue."
End Sub

Function AlphaNumericOnly(strSource As String)
Dim i As Integer
Dim strResult As String
For i = 1 To Len(strSource)
    Select Case Asc(Mid(strSource, i, 1))
        Case 33 To 59, 63 To 126 'assuming these ASCII chars are useful
            strResult = strResult & Mid(strSource, i, 1)
        Case Else
            strResult = strResult & " "
    End Select
Next
AlphaNumericOnly = strResult
End Function
```